# Azure frontdoor compliant RegEx rule for /users/*

Tags: regex, azure-front-door

I'm trying to create a "Azure front door" compliant regex that matches `/users/*` URL pathname patterns. But not `/users/*/` or `/users/*/profile` or `/users/*/<anything at all>`

I've tried without escaping as it looks like front door escapes for you.

```
^/users/([^/]+?)(?:/)?$
```

and this

```
^/users/[^/]+?$
```

But this doesn't work, I'm assuming because of the "?" which would count as a back reference? Any ideas on how to create a compliant regex, happy to try anything for anyone who doesn't have front door to test.

docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rules-match-conditions?pivots=front-door-standard-premium&tabs=portal#regular-expressions

=== EDIT ===

Iv'e accepted the below answer, but I think the culprit is RegEx's matching a preceeding "/", every other operator in front door rules seems to want a preceeding "/" except RegEx, without this it seems to work as expected in some basic testing.

With this in mind I've accepted the below answer but I have a feeling (without trying) that some of the original formats will work.

Comment: I think that the pattern would be `^/users/[^/]+$` but how did it not work? Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, for gif refer to post below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```cs
^/users/[^/\s]+$
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `/users/` - a fixed string
- `[^/\s]+` - one or more chars other than `/` and whitespace
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Starting to think Azure Front Door's "RegEx" is just completely broken. Zero examples online, the only tests I could get working using it basically look like plain text but not regex, Iv'e attached a GIF showing even this doesn't work escaped, unescaped, but does work using "Wildcard" but "Wildcard" matches anywhere in the path, rather than from the start.

(Gif enroute)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rOKKHLh

Shows it not working escaped, unescaped, but working with wildcard. And no it's not just about "waiting" long enough for it to take effect in my own testing i cache purged, waited like 10mins, spam refreshed and nothing

Comment: Iv'e opened a ticket with Azure to see what they say.

Comment: preceeding "/" is the issue in regex, left edit in original post accepted your answer but think some original formats will work

Comment: @ShanonJackson The more universal form of the regex is `^/users/[^/ ]+$` and POSIX variation is `^/users/[^/[:space:]]+$`. If these are not accepted there is certainly some bug or the regex support is not actually implemented there.

Comment: I found this and it could be of help : https://regexr.com/4kurg

Comment: @HuyTran I prefer [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fTkatc/2).